# Angular: URL changes after hitting refresh in prod mode

Tags: angular

I have built and deployed an angular application to an HTTP server. Below is how I am requesting the `index.html` page.

http://localhost:8080/contextRoot/index.html

The page loads and the URL changes to http://localhost:8080/contextRoot/XYZ

When I refresh this page, it says Error 404, Not Found.

How do I ask angular to not change the URL to http://localhost:8080/contextRoot/XYZ and instead use something like http://localhost:8080/contextRoot/index.html#Login like how AngularJS does

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

An Angular app is a Single Page App (SPA).

The Single Page is called index.html

No matter what the route/URL is you always serve up index.html

Angular-CLI dev server AKA Webpack dev server configures this out the box.

When you deploy your Angular App to a different web server you need to configure this yourself.

Just Google "NGINX configuration for Angular Single Page App" or
"Apache configuration for Single Page App"

And then configure your webserver accordingly.

PS The reason you got a 404 on refresh is because the default behaviour for your webserver is to look for /contextRoot/XYZ/index.html which obviously does not exist. You need to override this default behaviour as discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on nginx? If you are running your production build in nginx make sure to put this code in your configuration file

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.
}
```

Comment: No I am deploying it to http preview server. The prod server would be websphere mostly.